# how can I get complete header info from urlib2 request?

Tags: python, html, urllib2

I am using the python urllib2 library for opening URL, and what I want is to get the complete header info of the request. When I use `response.info` I only get this:

```
Date: Mon, 15 Aug 2011 12:00:42 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.0 (Unix)
Last-Modified: Tue, 01 May 2001 18:40:33 GMT
ETag: "13ef600-141-897e4a40"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 321
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

I am expecting the complete info as given by live_http_headers (add-on for firefox), e.g:

```
http://www.yellowpages.com.mt/Malta-Web/127151.aspx

GET /Malta-Web/127151.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.yellowpages.com.mt
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: __utma=156587571.1883941323.1313405289.1313405289.1313405289.1;    __utmz=156587571.1313405289.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 141
Date: Mon, 15 Aug 2011 12:17:25 GMT
Location: http://www.trucks.com.mt
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET, UrlRewriter.NET 2.0.0
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=zhnqh5554omyti55dxbvmf55; path=/; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: private
```

My request function is:

```
def dorequest(url, post=None, headers={}):
    cOpener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookielib.CookieJar()))
    urllib2.install_opener( cOpener )
    if post:
        post = urllib.urlencode(post)
    req = urllib2.Request(url, post, headers)
    response   = cOpener.open(req)
    print response.info()  // this does not give complete header info, how can i get complete header info??
    return response.read()
 url = 'http://www.yellowpages.com.mt/Malta-Web/127151.aspx'
 html = dorequest(url)
```

Is it possible to achieve the desired header info details by using urllib2? I don't want to switch to httplib.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those *are* all of the headers the server is sending when you do the request with `urllib2`.

Firefox is showing you the headers it's sending to the server as well.

When the server gets those headers from Firefox, some of them may trigger it to send back additional headers, so you end up with more response headers as well.

Duplicate the exact headers Firefox sends, and you'll get back an identical response.

Edit: That `location` header is sent by the page that does the redirect, not the page you're redirected to. Just use `response.url` to get the location of the page you've been sent to.

That first URL uses a 302 redirect. If you don't want to follow the redirect, but see the headers from the first page instead, use a [`URLOpener`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.URLopener) instead of a `FancyURLOpener`, which automatically follows redirects.

Comment: thanks for quick response, can you give precise solution to my problem also? is this achievable in the current scenario?

Comment: i got your answer, basically i want to have the value of variable `Location` which is `http://www.trucks.com.mt`, this site has some mechanism to redirect to this page when request is made by this url `http://www.yellowpages.com.mt/Malta-Web/127151.aspx`,  so can we catch extra headers which is sent by server?

Comment: i wanted to capture the redirected URL, so as by your suggestion `response.url` solved my problem, it gives me URL of the redirected page, cheers :-)

Comment: if the urllib2 automatically follows redirects then why it does not add extra headers which is sent by the redirected URL? (i'll marked this question as solved after answer of this question, if this question is debatable i'll post it in discussion, please suggest??)

Comment: Because they're not the headers of the page you received, so it would be incorrect to list them as part of its headers -- think of it like viewing the properties of a page you've been redirected to in Firefox - you won't see the headers of the page that redirected you. If you want to see that, you have to use a `URLOpener` to intercept that step of the operation.

Answer (score 0):

I see that server returns `HTTP/1.1 302 Found` - HTTP redirect.

urllib automatically follow redirects, so headers returned by urllib is headers from http://www.trucks.com.mt, not http://www.yellowpages.com.mt/Malta-Web/127151.aspx

Comment: yes i know that the urllib automatically follows the redirected url, but i want to capture the redirected url, unfortunately the site is under construction and there is no home page link in the content (follow this link `http://www.trucks.com.mt` and view its source code) otherwise i could have used regex and taken url from its home page.